# Java Loop Not Printing Result As Expected

Tags: java, for-loop, output

```
package com.company;

public class Main {

    public static int deleteFives(int start, int end) {
        int count = 0;
        for (int j = start; start < end; j++) {
            count++;
        }
        return count;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int result = deleteFives(1, 100);
        System.out.println(result);
    }

}
```

This loop is giving no output when I actually call the method.  I'm simply trying to have the "count" display.  My output is literally blank.  I'm very confused, as I can't see any flaws.

Comment: `start < end` that's always true. You meant `j < end`.

Answer (score 1):

because j was not used in loop definition. You wrote start < end in your code instead of j < end. Code below is printing result

```
public static int deleteFives(int start, int end) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int j = start; j < end; j++) {
        count++;
    }
    return count;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int result = deleteFives(1, 100);
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Variable J isn't used to compare. Swap variable J with start in the condition check.

Answer (score 0):

See this and Practice like this:

```
package com.practice;

public class Main {

    private static int startCounting(int start, int end) {
        int count = 0;
        while(start++<end)
            ++count;
        return count;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int countingResult = startCounting(1, 100);
        System.out.println(countingResult);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

start < end seems wrong in the loop. 
I think it should be j< end